# Can I parametrize the Office 365 subscription that I connect to in my Azure Logic App?

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-logic-apps

I've created a fairly simple [Azure Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/logic/) that connects to an Office 365 subscription, searches for a user and outputs the user's details to a storage blob.

It looks like this:
[image]

I would like to re-use this Logic App to perform the exact same steps but targeting several other Office 365 subscriptions.

Is it possible for me to parametrize the Office 365 subscription id so that I can run the same app against different subscriptions? Something like the "Change connection" feature shown above, only done programmatically?

Notes:

1. I'm thinking it could be ideal to pass in the Office 365 subscription id into the Logic App via a manual HTTP trigger.
2. Assume I have been granted access permissions to all Office 365 subscriptions via an Azure AD web application (multi-tenant).

Comment: Hi @urig, i tried answering your inquiry below. if you find the answer helpful.may you mark it as answer

Comment: Thanks @RamiSarieddine. I usually leave questions open for a few days to give more people motivation to answer. I'll review in a couple of days and will surely accept your answer assuming no one provides a better answer.

Comment: I hear you. thanks for the feedback nevertheless. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently it is not possible to parametrize the Office 365 subscription id so that you can run the same app against different subscriptions.
If you view the code behind this, there is 1 trigger and followed by an action, every action connects to a single SaaS app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible via a multi-tenant Azure AD app. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/) is an example.

Comment: Thanks. I know a multi-tenant Azure AD web app can do this. My question is - and I'll edit to make it clearer - Can I make the Office 365 Connector get the subscription id as an input parameter?